# PHP get input value without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Guys i have foreach loop where i list some prices. All price have own input radio button.

By default only one price from looping is checked. I want to get that value when page is lodaed.

I have one session where i store number of days. Based on these days I get the price of cars.

```
$numDays = $_SESSION['days']; // 5
$calculate_km = $numDays * 140;  // 5*140km
```

So in page where i want to show total KM i use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['days']) {
    $numDays = $_SESSION['days'];
}else {
    // Show default selected radio button value
}
```

Problem is bcs price list with `radio` is on the some page and there is no sumbiting

**My loop:**

```
<?php if($prices = getCarPricePeriod($car->ID, $od, $do)):?>
    <?php $first = true; ?>
        <?php foreach ($prices as $price): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $price['value'];?>" <?= $first ? 'checked' : '' ?>> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price_name" value=" <?= $price['name'];?>">&euro;/per day</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php $first = false; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Total KM : <span> <?= $numDays * 140 ;?> </span>
```

Only is posible to get that value if i submit that form. So i need `js` for this or any way to do this in `php`

Comment: Where you want to use it?

Comment: On the some page where is radio btn

Comment: Please discribe more the context _I want to get that value when page is lodaed_ (then when you will get it what you want to do?) the context is not clear.

Comment: Just a second i will update my question.

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question ?

Comment: Is there an extra `>` at end of   `<?= $price['value'];?>" <?= $first ? 'checked' : '' ?>>` ?

Comment: @guest271314 That's the closing tag of the `<input` I think. It should probably be `/>`

Comment: nope that is all. with `$first` i select first item `checked` in loop

Comment: Simple questuin. If `SESSION['days'] ` exist set session value. If not exist get value from selected radio button with `js`. How to put execute that js in that variable if session is not definded

Comment: @Zend _"If SESSION['days'] exist set session value. If not exist get value from selected radio button with js. How to put execute that js in that variable if session is not definded"_ What do you mean by "get value" ? Resend value back to `php` ? Could you achieve this in `php` `if(isset($_SESSION['days']) {
    $numDays = $_SESSION['days'];
}else {
    $numDays = $price['name']
}` ?

Comment: if session does not exist by default return with js radio value. that is all. I dont expect nothing else. I only have problem how to bring that  js value in `else` statement. If i just in js set `$(selector).val(123)` all time is `123` session value does not override js value

Comment: Not following logic. Do you want to post value of radio `input` back to `php` without submitting `form` at page load ?

Comment: @Zend you could achieve that just by php as mentioned in guest comment.

Comment: This work only when is session is defined. But when is not defined no. Bcs idk how to get that radio value. This wll work if in else i put default value... Idk what to do i dont have more inspiration

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is "how to send data from client-side to server-side", then the answer is AJAX.

Take a look at W3School's AJAX tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

**EDIT 1**

for javascript, this should do it:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=radio]:checked").getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: I dont want to send data i need just value for other calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get that value when page is lodaed.

Use `.ready()` , selector `$("tr input:checked")` , `.val()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = $("tr input:checked").val()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without submit, you need JavaScript to do that, like this:

```
<script>
    var p = document.getElementByName("price");
</script>
```